# Is Shiva god of only Sanyasis ? Does he give boon to worldly people?

Tags: shiva

Shiva is the prominent god of Sanyasis or those whose current aim is to get Moksha.
Is Shiva also the god of people who live worldy life ? Or Should worldly people worship  Vishnu instead ?

Comment: Lord shiva is called Vishwanatha, that is the lord of this vishwa, which includes everyone